# Nextflow: output not being "found", despite setting publishDir

Tags: nextflow

I have the following nextflow script:

```
echo true                                                                       
                                                                                
wd = "$params.wd"                                                               
geoid = "$params.geoid"                                                         
                                                                                
                                                                                
process step1 {                                                                 
                                                                                
 publishDir = "$wd/data/"                                                       
                                                                                
 input:                                                                         
  val celFiles from "$wd/data/$geoid"                                           
                                                                                
 output:                                                                        
  file "${geoid}_datFiles.RData" into channel                                   
                                                                                
 """                                                                            
 Rscript $wd/scripts/step1.R $celFiles $wd/data/${geoid}_datFiles.RData         
                                                                                
 """                                                                            
                                                                                
}
```

The Rscript contains the following commands:

```
step1=function(WD,
               celFiles,
               output) {
 
  library(affy)

  datFiles=ReadAffy(celfile.path=paste0(WD,"/",celFiles))
  
  save(datFiles,file=output)

}

args=commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
WD=args[1]
celFiles=args[2]
output=args[3]

step1(WD,celFiles,output)
```

When it runs, the output file is saved in the directory I want ($wd/data/${geoid}_datFiles.RData). Given that publishDir points to the same directory, I would expect output (defined as "${geoid}_datFiles.RData") to be available under the publishDir directory.

However, I get the following error:

```
  Missing output file(s) `GSE4290_datFiles.RData` expected by process `step1`
```

The log file suggests that nextflow is still looking for the output in the workflow created directory:

```
Process `step1` is unable to find [UnixPath]: `/Users/rebeccaeliscu/Desktop/workflow/affymetrix/nextflow/work/92/42afb131a36eb32ed780bd1bf3bc3b/GSE4290_datFiles.RData`
```

The complete log file:

```
Nov-12 17:55:39.611 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.Launcher - $> nextflow run main.nf
Nov-12 17:55:39.945 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.07.1
Nov-12 17:55:39.968 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - Launching `main.nf` [infallible_brahmagupta] - revision: d68e496ea0
Nov-12 17:55:40.026 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Found config local: /Users/rebeccaeliscu/Desktop/workflow/affymetrix/nextflow/nextflow.config
Nov-12 17:55:40.029 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Parsing config file: /Users/rebeccaeliscu/Desktop/workflow/affymetrix/nextflow/nextflow.config
Nov-12 17:55:40.140 [main] DEBUG nextflow.config.ConfigBuilder - Applying config profile: `standard`
Nov-12 17:55:41.288 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session uuid: 94f22a74-2a63-4a87-9fb3-33cf925a5a74
Nov-12 17:55:41.288 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Run name: infallible_brahmagupta
Nov-12 17:55:41.289 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Executor pool size: 4
Nov-12 17:55:41.326 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.CmdRun -
  Version: 20.07.1 build 5412
  Created: 24-07-2020 15:18 UTC (08:18 PDT)
  System: Mac OS X 10.15.7
  Runtime: Groovy 2.5.11 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_111-b14
  Encoding: UTF-8 (UTF-8)
  Process: 46458@Rebeccas-MacBook-Pro-6.local.ucsf.edu [10.49.41.197]
  CPUs: 4 - Mem: 8 GB (708.4 MB) - Swap: 2 GB (927 MB)
Nov-12 17:55:41.353 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Work-dir: /Users/rebeccaeliscu/Desktop/workflow/affymetrix/nextflow/work [Mac OS X]
Nov-12 17:55:41.354 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Script base path does not exist or is not a directory: /Users/rebeccaeliscu/Desktop/workflow/affymetrix/nextflow/bin
Nov-12 17:55:41.594 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Observer factory: TowerFactory
Nov-12 17:55:41.598 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Observer factory: DefaultObserverFactory
Nov-12 17:55:41.911 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session start invoked
Nov-12 17:55:42.309 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Launching execution
Nov-12 17:55:42.331 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Workflow process names [dsl1]: step1
Nov-12 17:55:42.334 [main] WARN  nextflow.script.BaseScript - The use of `echo` method has been deprecated
Nov-12 17:55:42.495 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Nov-12 17:55:42.496 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Nov-12 17:55:42.508 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.Executor - [warm up] executor > local
Nov-12 17:55:42.521 [main] DEBUG n.processor.LocalPollingMonitor - Creating local task monitor for executor 'local' > cpus=4; memory=8 GB; capacity=4; pollInterval=100ms; dumpInterval=5m
```

Answer (score 3):

Your output declaration is looking for a file in the current workDir: `"${geoid}_datFiles.RData"`, but your Rscript is writing to: `$wd/data/${geoid}_datFiles.RData`. If you change your command to:

```
Rscript $wd/scripts/step1.R $celFiles ${geoid}_datFiles.RData
```

Then Nextflow should be able to find the output file. The publishDir directive will then 'publish' it to the defined publishDir.

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks for your response. I have adjusted the naming of the output files to be just the file name, as you suggest. While the workflow now succeeds, I still don't find the outputs where I want per publishDir, i.e. "$wd/data". They are instead under the unique workflow "work/..." directory.

Comment: Update: I had moved the 'publishDir' directive to the top of the document. I guess it wasn't reaching the processes, because when I added 'publishDir' to each process, I got the desired behavior. Is there better way to do this, i.e. without being redundant and including publishDir in each process?

Comment: Well, NF runs each process in a unique workDir (i.e. "work/...") so you should always expect output files under that directory (assuming your process succeeds). But looking at your code again, I think you have a typo on your publishDir line; i.e. there's an `=` sign where there shouldn't be; all you need is: `publishDir "$wd/data"`. I think it's ok to be explicit, perhaps something like: ```publishDir(path: "${params.publish_dir}/${task.process.replaceAll(':', '/')}", enabled: params.publish_everything || params.publish_step1, mode: params.publish_mode,)```

Comment: Thanks again for your response!